# How can I stop the badge (green item in final column) from stretching to the full width of the cell (and instead wrapping the length of the text)?

Tags: html, css

I need the green badge to stop stretching the full length of the cell. How can I accomplish this?

Using HTML & CSS as the element is an HTML Embed in a Webflow Site.

Here is a reference of the current state:
[image]

Here is the current code:

```
<style>
        table {
            width:100%;
            border:1px solid #262626;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            padding:20px;
        }
        table th {
            border:1px solid #262626;
            padding:20px;
            background: #171717;
            color: #fafafa;
        }
        table td {
            border:1px solid #262626;
            text-align: left;
            padding:20px;
            background: #0a0a0a;
            color: #fafafa;
        }
    .table-badge {
        padding: 4px 12px;
      background-color: #14532D;
      border-radius: 20px;
      color: #86EFAC;
      width: auto;
    }
    </style>
  <p style="font-size: 1.25rem; margin-bottom: 1rem">Production</p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Hourly</th>
                <th>Availability</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Interaction Designer</td>
                <td>North America</td>
                <td>## USD</td>
                <td><p class="table-badge">Available</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Production Designer</td>
                <td>South America</td>
                <td>## USD</td>
                <td>Available</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Senior Copywriter</td>
                <td>North America</td>
                <td>## USD</td>
                <td>Partially Avail.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've attempted a few different CSS declarations and they did not provide the sought result.

Comment: `p` is a block element by default - so apply `display: inline` or `inline-block`. Or make this not a paragraph, but a `span` to begin with - a single word indicating a status, is hardly a "paragraph of text" in the first place.